# Converting a String to number and Back to String

Tags: c, string, int

I have a String for example `"23:0"` which is a hour format.  I need to convert this to a int so I can add time to it for example.  I have a string `"23:0"` I need to add 6 hours which would be `"6:0"` which would then give me `"5:0"`, and then convert this back to a string.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated :)

---

When I write my function I get an error "cannot convert 'string to char*' in initiliazation" my function looks like this:

```
int convert(String x){
    char *str = x;
    int hour; int minute;
    sscanf(str, "%d:%d", &hour, &minute);
    return hour;
}
convert(time) //time is a String for example 23:0
```

Comment: One comment miles down says _'Oh, I made a typo: I really have "23:0"'._  (a) Edit the question, and (b) In that case, if you are on POSIX machine, you could/should investigate `strptime()` to convert from string to time and `strftime()` to convert from time to string.  However, it might be overkill for just hours and minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the string is in a particular format ([hour]:[min]), you can use `sscanf()` to scan the string.  Since the string is in an expected format, this would be the easiest to do.  Otherwise you'd use the other methods described by everyone else.

```
char *str = "23:0";
int hour, min;
sscanf(str, "%d:%d", &hour, &min);
/* hour = 23
   min  = 0
*/
```

After that you can do the math that you need and spit the results back out to a buffer.

```
char buf[100];
hour = (hour + 6) % 24;
snprintf(buf, 100, "%d:%d", hour, min);
```

Comment: The question says '23.0' not '23:0'.  Also, 23+6 = 5 (modulo 24).

Comment: @Jonathan: According to the comment in Santiago's Answer, it was supposed to be `"23:0"`.  So I'm going on that.  As for the addition, I fixed that but the stupid draft didn't save and lost my change... easily fixed tho.

Comment: when I write my function I get an error "cannot convert  'string to char*' in initiliazation"

my function looks like this.

Code:

int convert(String x){

  
  
char *str = x;
  
 int hour;
 int minute;
 
 sscanf(str, "%d:%d", &hour, &minute);
 
 return hour;


}

convert(time) //time is a String for example 23:0

Comment: @user: In C, there is no true "String" type so it must have been a type you defined.  How was it defined?  p.s., put all the new code that you come up with as an edit into your question above.  It's hard to read when put in a comment and you shouldn't be adding this information as "answers".

Comment: I have feedtime defined as a String my function takes that String and tries the char *str = x which gives me the error.

Comment: @user: What I meant was that somewhere in your code, you've defined a new type `String` (or made a macro).  What was written in your code?  e.g., `typedef char *String;` or `#define String char *`, something along those lines.

Comment: The only defines I have in my code are the ones in the TimeSerial arduino sketch which are 

<code>#define TIME_MSG_LEN  11   // time sync to PC is HEADER followed by unix time_t as ten ascii digits
#define TIME_HEADER  'T'   // Header tag for serial time sync message
#define TIME_REQUEST  7    // ASCII bell character requests a time sync message </code>

Comment: Nothing else defined anywhere.

Comment: I get the same error with a new sketch with just the convert function by itself.

Comment: by the way if I write char *str = "23:0"; that works but when I write char *str = x; where x is a string it gives me the the error.

Comment: How was the variable `time` initialized when you tried to call your `convert()` function?  The problem could be that you just wrote the wrong function signature and your function should take `char *` instead of `String`.

Comment: time is initialized as


String time;

When i use the convert function time will be anything between "0:0" and "23:0"

Comment: I've changed my time variable to char
<hr>
and I've changed my function to this:

int convert(char* x){


char *str = x;

 
 int hour;
 int minute;
 
 sscanf(str, "%d:%d", &hour, &minute);
 
 return hour;


}
That complies fine, however when I try to call the convert function with convert(time); it give me an error saying invalid conversion from 'char' to 'char*'

Comment: In that case, you should not be using `String` as the type then, period.  It's not a valid type nor do you explicitly define one.  Just use `char *`.  Make sure the variable `time` is also the same type.  i.e., `char *time;`

Comment: So I finally got it to work correctly however, when I write Serial.println(time); it gives me the correct addition but it appends a different character every time.  
6:0`
6:0`
6:0t
6:0bÿ


any ideas?

Comment: I'm sorry but you're going to have to post _all_ the _relevant_ code in your question.  We're getting nowhere without it and I really can't be waiting here hoping you'll fill in the rest of the holes in a dozen other comments.

Answer (score 0):

There are simple functions for these simple tasks in the standard library. Look up `atoi()` and `atof()` for string-to-number conversion, and `sprintf()` for number to string.

**Edit**: example.
Code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

 char string[10];
 int n1, n2, result;

 n1 = atoi("23");
 n2 = 6;

 result = (n1 + n2) % 24;

 sprintf(string, "%d", result);
 printf("Result: %s\n", string);

 return 0;
}
```

stdout:

```
Result: 5
```

Cheers!

Comment: I just realized I had a mistype.  The string I have is not 23.0 but 23:0.  Any ideas? For converting them, I don't believe theres a function for that since its not really a number...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a few things done at once (even though this really sounds like a homework assignment). The very basic example would be:

```
char *x = "23.0";
char *y = "6.0";
float result = atof(x) + atof(y);
float result_24h = result % 24; // Modulo to get remainer only
char result_str[32]; // bad bad form, but good enough for this example
sprintf(result_str,"%f",result_24h);
```

At least something along those lines, written off the top of my head so apologies in advance for any typos/syntax errors;

Comment: `strtod()` or `strtof()` is usually preferred to `atof()`, as the latter is often referred to as "deprecated" on *nix systems (despite the C standard), and because the former functions have predictable behavior on inability to parse, as well as overflow/underflow.